# Error in Stan Code when variable is clearly defined

Tags: r, runtime-error, stan

I am getting the following error in my Stan code:

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:
No matches for: 

  gpareto_lcdf(real, real, real)

Available argument signatures for gpareto_lcdf:

  gpareto_lcdf(vector, real, real)

 error in 'modelafda6ff99d79_gpd' at line 54, column 50
  -------------------------------------------------
    52:   for (i in 1:n) {
    53:     if (censored[i]) {
    54:       target += gpareto_lcdf(value[i] | k, sigma);  
                                                         ^
    55:     } else {
  -------------------------------------------------

Error in stanc(file = file, model_code = model_code, model_name = model_name,  : 
  failed to parse Stan model 'gpd' due to the above error.
```

In my R studio version, it seems to be complaining about the sigma parameter and not being able to find a match for it. I don't understand why this is an issue given that sigma is defined in my gpareto_lcdf. Here is the code that I am using:

```
functions {
  real gpareto_lpdf(vector y, real k, real sigma) {
    // generalised Pareto log pdf 
    int N = rows(y);
    real inv_k = inv(k);
    if (k<0 && max(y)/sigma > -inv_k)
      reject("k<0 and max(y)/sigma > -1/k; found k, sigma =", k, sigma)
    if (sigma<=0)
      reject("sigma<=0; found sigma =", sigma)
    if (fabs(k) > 1e-15)
      return -(1+inv_k)*sum(log1p((y) * (k/sigma))) -N*log(sigma);
    else
      return -sum(y)/sigma -N*log(sigma); // limit k->0
  }

  real gpareto_lcdf(vector y, real k, real sigma) {
    // generalised Pareto log cdf
    real inv_k = inv(k);
    if (k<0 && max(y)/sigma > -inv_k)
      reject("k<0 and max(y)/sigma > -1/k; found k, sigma =", k, sigma)
    if (sigma<=0)
      reject("sigma<=0; found sigma =", sigma)
    if (fabs(k) > 1e-15)
      return sum(log1m_exp((-inv_k)*(log1p((y) * (k/sigma)))));
    else
      return sum(log1m_exp(-(y)/sigma)); // limit k->0
  }
}

data {
  // the input data
  int<lower = 1> n;                      
  real<lower = 0> value[n];              
  int<lower = 0, upper = 1> censored[n];  

  // parameters for the prior
  real<lower = 0> a;
  real<lower = 0> b;
}

parameters {
  real k;
  real sigma;
}

model {
 // prior
 k ~ gamma(a, b);
 sigma ~ gamma(a,b);

 // likelihood
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (censored[i]) {
      target += gpareto_lcdf(value[i] | k, sigma);  
    } else {
      target += gpareto_lpdf(value[i] | k, sigma);
    }
  }
}
```

Clearly sigma is defined in the gpareto_lcdf and so I am unsure why Stan is complaining about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in the `likelihood` section of the `model` block doesn't match the way you have defined the `gpareto...()` functions in the `functions` block. The `gpareto` functions take a vector as the first argument but instead you are looping through and trying to pass a single element of `value` each time. That's why you get the error that the data types you are passing to `gpareto_lcdf()` do not match the "signature" of the function. The function expects the first argument to be a `vector`, the second to be a `real`, and the third to be a `real`. But you are passing three `real`s.

The error has nothing to do with `sigma`. The `^` symbol is pointing to the entire function call to `gpareto_lcdf()` and just happens to be pointing near where the word `sigma` is, but the error isn't related to `sigma`.

To fix this error, you would need to do one of the following:

- Redefine the `gpareto()` functions to take three `real` arguments and keep your loop in the `model` block as is.
- Rewrite your `model` block to not use a loop and instead be vectorized.

I'm not sure the vectorization will work with the condition you have in the `model` block so you may be forced to go with the first solution.

I would recommend posting this question on the [Stan forum](https://discourse.mc-stan.org) where you may get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the fantastic answer!